# Script Works in Console but not in QGIS Script Editor

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I've recently started working with Python in QGIS and I've been trying to make a script that dissolves a polygon layer and saves the output in the same folder as the input, something I believe isn't possible to do with QGIS Graphical Modeller.

The code I've written is as follows:

```
processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer(),'FIELD':[],'OUTPUT':iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('2D', 2)[0] +"2D Simulation Elements dissolved.shp"})
iface.addVectorLayer((iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('2D', 2)[0] +"2D Simulation Elements dissolved.shp"),"","ogr")
```

It works fine in the console, however when I put it in the Script Toolbox it fails with the following error:

[image: Traceback Error]

The code is confusing me cause, I obviously don't have 224 lines of code for it have an error there...
I've looked online and followed the suggestion to add the following on top of my code:

```
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)
```

But it didn't make my script work as well.

Comment: you need import QgsApplication using  `from qgis.core import QgsApplication`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when trying to run a script outside of the python console you must define iface and processing by adding

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import  (QgsProcessing)

import processing
```

Should run now outside the python console from the processing toolbox

Comment: It works, but i am getting an error when i ran it, but i am happy as long as it works.